# Hierarchical Clustering with Flann opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a problem, I need to clusterize a set of points in an unknown number of clusters. I use opencv but there is not documentation about `cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering`. Someone that use this function could help me? Another question is about the return value that should be the number of clusters, but how could I understand which are the cluster?
I created a `cv::Mat points` with dimensions `n x 2` where n is the number of points.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation for this function, [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_clustering.html). The return value is indeed the number of clusters found. I GUESS that you then find to which cluster belong each feature vector in the const Mat& features parameter using Mat& centers.

Comment: What is meant with the 'Distance d=Distance()' value? It is not an integer, but a template?

Comment: The default value for distance is an object of Distance type, constructed by the call of Distance()