# What is the parameter `Distance d = Distance()` in OpenCV's hierachicalClustering function?

Tags: c++, opencv

I've gone through questions, the source code, and other examples, and I can't for the life of me understand what the `Distance d = Distance()` parameter means in the function

[`template<typename Distance> int flann::hierarchicalClustering(const Mat& features, Mat& centers, const cvflann::KMeansIndexParams& params, Distance d=Distance())`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/flann/doc/flann_clustering.html#flann-hierarchicalclustering-distance)

It's addressed in the comments of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178882/hierarchical-clustering-with-flann-opencv), but I can't find the Distance type anywhere. I've imported the following files:

```
#include "opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/flann/flann.hpp"
```

I've checked the `cv`, `cvflann`, and `cv::flann` namespaces and can't find anything.

Here's my code:

```
int tmp = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<cv::L2<float>>(descriptors, centers, params, ______ );
```

The ___ is obviously where this last parameter goes. I've tried something like `cv::L2<float>()` but that doesn't work either.

In the source code it looks like a template.

I've also tried:

```
int tmp = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<float, float>(descriptors, centers, params);
```

and I get the error "no instance of overloaded function "cv::flann::hierachicalClustering" matches the argument list. Argument types are: (cv::Mat, cv::Mat, cv::KMeansIndexParams).

I am using OpenCV 2.4.11.

Any ideas?

There's also more documentation in the [FLANN user manual](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mariusm/uploads/FLANN/flann_manual-1.6.pdf). It looks like it was copied verbatim into OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter `Distance d = Distance()` is a default method argument that sets a distance algorithm. Usually, this will be `FLANN_DIST_L2`. Why you can't find the `Distance` "type" anywhere is because it's actually a `typename`. OpenCV opted to use C++ specialization (via templates) instead of inheritance to make sure that different distance functions have the same traits.

This is a nontrivial subject, so http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mxc++-item-4.htm should provide a fairly painless introduction. If I whet your appetite, check out Andrei Alexandrescu's seminal [Modern C++ Design](http://erdani.com/index.php/books/modern-c-design/).

Comment: Awesome thanks! This is a great explanation and I'd like to spend time going through the detaiils, but, in the short term, what is an example argument that could go in there? I tried `int tmp = cv::flann::hierarchicalClustering<cv::L2<float>>(descriptors, centers, params, cvflann::FLANN_DIST_L2);
` but no luck

Comment: @marcman: See `defines.h` for the full list, you should be able to use `FLANN_DIST_MANHATTAN`, `FLANN_DIST_L1`, `FLANN_DIST_MINKOWSKI` to name a few.

Comment: I tried cvflann::FLANN_DIST_L2 (I edited my above comment) and it still says it's unsupported. Apparently flann_distance_t is not appropriate there.

Comment: @marcman: I don't have OpenCV set up so I can't test stuff out myself, but reading some http://answers.opencv.org, it looks like it may be impossible to set a different distance metric because of some refactoring issues. Does something along the lines of `flann::hierarchicalClustering<cv::flann::Hamming<unsigned char> >` work?

Comment: It does not. Alas, I think this issue may exceed the depth of my understanding as far as C++ (and PLs in general) goes. I'm going to leave the question here and perhaps someone else has solved it, but in the meantime I'll just try a different clustering solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this for future reference, since I was just struggling with the OpenCV FLANN classes myself

This worked for me:

```
// define parameters
cvflann::KMeansIndexParams kmeansParams(10, 100, cvflann::FLANN_CENTERS_KMEANSPP);
// note cvflann - not cv::flann - namespace there

int nClusters = flann::hierarchicalClustering<flann::L2<float>>(samples, centers, kmeansParams );
// note regular flann namespace here
```

the issue was that marcman was using `<cv::L2<float>>` instead of `<flann::L2<float>>`

The flann namespaces are super confusing, and documentation is lacking

and it's a struggle to figure it out in the IDE due to the templating.